# pandas - dealing with multilayered columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read stock quotes from Yahoo finance using a library.
The returned data seems to have columns stacked over two levels:

[image]

I want to get rid of "Adj Close" and have a simple dataframe with just the ticker columns. How do I do this?

Comment: This is called a **multiindex**. You simply want to drop its 0'th level 'Adj Close'. See the many existing duplicate Q&A on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run:

```py
data[["Adj Close"]].columns

[Out]:
MultiIndex([('Adj Close', 'AAPL'),
            ('Adj Close', 'AMZN'),
            ('Adj Close', 'GOOG')],
           )
```

the output says that it is a multi-index.

You can use [droplevel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html). Drop it either using "name" or "level index".

In this case, we don't see any level names. So, use level index: `0` is for "Adj Close" and `1` is for ticker.

```py
data_adj_close = data[["Adj Close"]].droplevel(level=0, axis="columns")
data_adj_close.columns

[Out]:
Index(['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GOOG'], dtype='object')
```

Now you can select by ticker:

```py
data_adj_close["AAPL"]

[Out]:
Date
2022-01-03    180.959732
2022-01-04    178.663071
2022-01-05    173.910660
...
```